# How to handle 'document' and 'localstorage' errors in Ionic Server-Side Rendering?

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, local-storage, server-side-rendering

**Problem running 'localstorage' and 'document' on Ionic SSR environment**

I'm trying to implement Ionic Server Side rendering (alongside Angular) in my current Ionic Mobile Project, however I'm getting erros in the compilation process regarding the use of 'document' and 'localstorage', which are browser APIs that I'm using and that the Node.js server-side environment doesn't recognize. What can I do to replace those functions?

Comment: nothing, ionic components are for browser, not server